# Spring OAuth 2 Correct way to refresh token on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring, oauth

I'm using the following logic to refresh my token when it is expired on the Angular side:

```
    $rootScope.$on('oauth:error', function (event, rejection) {

    if ('invalid_grant' === rejection.data.error) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('error:emitted',"User or password incorrect");
        return;
    }

    // Refresh token when a `invalid_token` error occurs.
    if ('invalid_token' === rejection.data.error) {
        return OAuth.getRefreshToken().then(function (result) {
            $cookies.putObject("token", result.data, true);
    })
    }

    // Redirect to `/login` with the `error_reason`.
    return $window.location.href = '/login?error_reason=' + rejection.data.error;
});
```

The logic is: When the user call a service on the moment that the token is expired, and the token is passive to do a refresh token, the server will return "invalid_token".

My $rootScope will listen to this specific error 'oauth:error' and if it is the type of 'invalid_token', then a refresh token is called to the server.

The logic seems correct. However, when  the token got invalid,spring deleted the token from the database, and I was unable to do the refresh token.

**The question is**: Based on the spec of OAuth2, it is correct to change this behavior of spring to instead of delete the token when it is invalid, keep it on the database, so I can do a refresh token?